# Azure API Management JWT token policy

Tags: azure-api-management, jwt

I am trying to setup policy for JWT in Azure portal and I have searched and pasted almost all solutions available in net, but none seem to work. Here is there policy that I have setup:-

```
<policies>
   <inbound>
      <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" require-scheme="Bearer">
         <issuer-signing-keys>
            <key>X3IwT3A3bkVfZn40aHkueTBuX2lWd0J6OWNsMjI2Uk9WZw==</key>
         </issuer-signing-keys>
         <decryption-keys>
            <key>X3IwT3A3bkVfZn40aHkueTBuX2lWd0J6OWNsMjI2Uk9WZw==</key>
         </decryption-keys>
         <audiences>
            <audience>api://53cd59c4-53e7-46e6-890b-1dcac2cb2423</audience>
         </audiences>
         <issuers>
            <issuer>https://sts.windows.net/5181d074-dbc6-49e9-9ada-051bc62d5e3e/</issuer>
         </issuers>
         <required-claims>
            <claim name="scope" match="any" separator=" ">
               <value>Files.Read</value>
            </claim>
         </required-claims>
      </validate-jwt>
   </inbound>
   <backend>
      <base />
   </backend>
   <outbound>
      <base />
   </outbound>
   <on-error>
      <base />
   </on-error>
</policies>
```

Request:

```
GET https://insyncapim.azure-api.net/api/Product/api/Product HTTP/1.1
Host: insyncapim.azure-api.net
Authorization: Bearer {my JWT token}
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
Ocp-Apim-Trace: true
```

response:

```
content-length: 85
content-type: application/json
date: Thu, 12 Nov 2020 09:13:53 GMT
ocp-apim-trace-location: https://apimstu4tludl9hfaq8f2v6o.blob.core.windows.net/apiinspectorcontainer/wEGj7uZ8ebXmIo1P1hgGvw2-16?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=sQ98cMJe58d6bJcmZ%2BRqGHtn6jk6S13p7ORbFlWkIwI%3D&se=2020-11-13T09%3A13%3A53Z&sp=r&traceId=3f4870770f544ed28962360a04112ef8
vary: Origin
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "message": "Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid."
}
```

trace:

```
api-inspector
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "https://insyncapim.azure-api.net/api/Product/api/Product",
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
                "value": {My subscription key}
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Site",
                "value": "cross-site"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Mode",
                "value": "cors"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Dest",
                "value": "empty"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Forwarded-For",
                "value": "182.75.240.158"
            },
            {
                "name": "Cache-Control",
                "value": "no-cache, no-store"
            },
            {
                "name": "Content-Type",
                "value": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept",
                "value": "*/*"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept-Encoding",
                "value": "gzip,deflate,br"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept-Language",
                "value": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
            },
            {
                "name": "Authorization",
                "value": "Bearer {my JWT token}
            },
            {
                "name": "Host",
                "value": "insyncapim.azure-api.net"
            },
            {
                "name": "Referer",
                "value": "https://apimanagement.hosting.portal.azure.net/"
            }
        ]
    }
}

api-inspector
{
    "configuration": {
        "api": {
            "from": "/api/Product",
            "to": null,
            "version": null,
            "revision": "1"
        },
        "operation": {
            "method": "GET",
            "uriTemplate": "/api/Product"
        },
        "user": "-",
        "product": "-"
    }
}
```

And I am trying to generate the access token using postman, the access token is getting generated. But whenever, I try to request the API using the access token, the result is always 401: Unauthorized.
I am trying it for the first time, plz help me out.

Comment: Could you please share the details of how did you generate the access token in postman ? And is this api just need `Files.Read` permission ?

Comment: And could you please share the full trace which location was provided in Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location.

Comment: Hi @HuryShen, I got all the credentials from App Registration -> Demo App -> Endpoints. Then, in POSTMAN from the authorization tab, I have selected the OAuth 2.0 -> Get New access token. The access token generated in this step is used for further API requests. I couldn't get any scope related documentation where valid scopes are mentioned and requesting the access token without scope was throwing error. I watched a youtube video he used this scope, so I used this scope.

Comment: It seems you do not know which scope the access token contain. You need to know which permission you want to assign to the app in your azure ad. If you have already assigned the permission to the app and also grant admin consent for it. You can copy your access token to [this](https://jwt.io/) page and decode the token. Then check if there is a `scope` field in the decoded token. I guess it may not exists a field in token, the field maybe named `scp` but not `scope`.

Comment: yes i have decoded the access token and it contains- "scp": "Files.Read profile openid email",

Comment: Ok, could you please change the `scope` in your apim policy to `scp`. Change to `<claim name="scp" match="any" separator=" ">` and then try again.

Comment: yes changed it to "scp" now response is: vary: Origin
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "message": "Invalid JWT."
}

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of how did you request the apim with the token in header ?

Comment: GET https://insyncapim.azure-api.net/api/Product/api/Product HTTP/1.1
Host: insyncapim.azure-api.net
Authorization: Bearer {my JWT token}
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
Ocp-Apim-Trace: true

Comment: @HuryShen, if you can help it would be great.

Comment: Sorry, I did some research but can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem I solved it by unchecking `Subscription required`. To do it go to `Your API management > APIs > Select your API's > Settings > Look for 'Subscription required' and uncheck it`.

[image]